# Bootstrap and jquery ui date picker not mixing well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site using bootstrap and I have a need to display a calendar when a textbox is clicked. I've done this on non bootstrap sites and it worked great, but in this bootstrap site the calendar does come up but it's background is transparent which makes it impossible to read with the stuff behind it showing through.

```
$(function () {
            $(".date-picker").datepicker();
}


<input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" id="inputCD" placeholder="Date" />
```

Comment: Maybe a z-index issue??

Comment: Maybe it's better to use bootstrap-datepicker.js? It shouldn't cause problems like yours.

Comment: I haven't seen that before. I'll give that one a try. Thanks.